# Firebase iOS query not ordering as expected

Tags: ios, firebase

I have saved my data using `childByAutoId` so that it is ordered chronologically in Firebase. When I query using the query below, and then I print the `snapshot.value` it prints in the orders as I expected --**ordered chronologically**--, but when I try to enumerate over `snapshot.value`, and when I try to get the keys with `[snap.value allkeys]`, they are no longer ordered chronologically. I have tried using `[self.refMyOrder queryOrderedByKey]` and `[self.refMyOrders queryOrderedByChild:@"timestamp"` for which I have a child `timestamp` that is a data-type `long` of the Epoch time. But still, it is not maintaining the desired order.

I understand that the underlying data structure of an NSDictionary is not an *ordered* data structure.

What am I doing wrong?

```
[self.refMyOrders observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"snapshot.value = %@", snapshot.value);
    NSLog(@"all keys = %@", [snapshot.value allKeys]);
}];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I read the `FDataSnapshot.h` header file that comes with the Firebase iOS SDK, and found a way to enumerate over the `snapshot` so that it remains in the proper order.

```
[self.refMyOrders observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    for (FDataSnapshot* child in snapshot.children) {
        NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", child.value[@"orderID"], child.value[@"timestamp"]);
    }
}];
```

This is exactly what I was looking for. I will leave this question here for future users. I couldn't find anything **this simple**.

Comment: There is a sample in the Firebase iOS development guide in the section on queries: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries . But it is indeed pretty well  hidden in there. ;-)

Comment: OMG, please tell me this ain't true... How can I achieve the same thing for snapshot.value ?